# use \partial sign from other packages, for example mathpazo

Tags: math-mode, mathpazo

I would like to include another `\partial` sign, for example the one from mathpazo. i found a way to do it but i'm not sure wether it will change other things as well, so is this the right approach?

```
\documentclass{article}
\DeclareSymbolFont{operator}{OML}{zplm}{m}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\p}{0}{operator}{"40} 
\usepackage{commath}

\newcommand*{\pfrac}[2]{\dfrac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\begin{document}
$\pfrac{^2 F}{x^2} =\dfrac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x^2}$
\end{document}
```

Best regards

Comment: Seems OP knows the symbol that he wants, but wants it from a different font.

Comment: yes, JPi is right, "all i want" is a more beautiful \partial sign.